# How do i retrive capital city or longitude and latitude because that's what openweathermap accepts and i only have country names?

Tags: json, symfony, openweathermap

I'm running a symfony 3.4 project using openweather-bundle to generate weather data and statistics and i want to search by country name but the API doesn't seem to support that, so i'm in a bind.

The only solution that comes up to mind is to get the latitude and longitude using JavaScript but i don't know how to handle that in the controller

Here is my controller

```
public function PaysMeteoAction($name)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $pays = $em->getRepository("AppBundle:Pays")->findOneBy(array('name' => $name));
    $openWeather = $this->get('dwr_open_weather');
    $weather = $openWeather->setType('Weather')->getByCityName('London');

    return $this->render('DwrOpenWeatherBundle:Default:weather-basic-large.html.twig', array(
        'weather' => $weather,
        'pays' => $pays,
    ));
}
```

The twig is default one provided by the bundle and my route is as follows

```
pays_meteo:
    path:     /meteo/{name}
    defaults: { _controller: "ExperienceBundle:Pays:PaysMeteo" }
```

Comment: Maybe you could store the capital of each country in your database and use that to call the open weather api. You can find a list here https://restcountries.eu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll just have to insert the capitals into the database.